# “Leaves are moved” or “leaves move”?

Tags: active-vs-passive

The leaves of a tree are moved by the wind. That is, the wind moves the leaves.

Can I just say “leaves move” in this situation? “move” here is an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends exactly what you want to say.

> - The leaves are moved by the wind.
> - The wind moves the leaves.

Both of these emphasize that the wind is what causes the leaves to move. Either is grammatical and natural.

As to the passive vs active voice issue, in his case the passive does not serve to obscure the causative agent (here the wind). They carry the same information, so this is just a matter of style.

> - The leaves move.
> - The leaves move from side to side.

Both of these say nothing about what causes the leaves to move. Either is grammatical and natural.

> - The leaves move in the wind.
> - The leaves move with the wind.

Both of these indicate a connection between the wind and the movement, but do not emphasize the wind as the actual cause of the movement. Either is grammatical and natural.

In any of these, there might be further specification, with "leaves" replaced by "leaves of a tree", "leaves of the tree"
"leaves from the oak tree", "Oak leaves" or any other more specific description of the leaves.